# Is it possible to create a feature for custom wallets that also have a bank account number?

Tags: development

The main problem I'm attempting to tackle is to create a feature that allows for wallets that are linked to a bank account which needs monitoring and transparency to prevent embezzling. Think something like a housing society's funds in a bank account no. 123XXX. If all of 123XXX's transactions are shown on the blockchain(by linking this account to a wallet), all spendings will be more transparent.

As pointed out by Murch, my attempted solution was this -

I am trying to modify the bitcoin protocol(possibly fork it and create an altcoin) that allows for the creation of **non-anonymous** wallets that have a publicly visible bank account(identity theft not an issue) as one of the fields on the Blockchain every time these wallets are part of a transaction.

Please guide me toward this.

Comment: Are you talking about forking Bitcoin into an alt-coin and adding this feature, or trying to do this on the existing Bitcoin blockchain?

Comment: "will also be displayed on the blockchain" doesn't make sense. This question seems like an XY-problem to me. What do you actually want to do?

Comment: Wallets are not announced to the network. Perhaps you should elaborate what you're trying to do, right now it sounds more like you should be aiming for a website than a modification of the Bitcoin protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be transparent in Bitcoin, there is little you need to do:

- All transactions are visible on the blockchain already.
- There is no need to connect addresses to your bank-account or any such thing.
- Instead, just use a single address for all your transactions and require documentation and vouchers for every payment on your website.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a poor understanding of how Bitcoin addresses work. When you create a Bitcoin address it **doesn't** appear anywhere. Not on the blockchain, not on someone else's computer. It exists only as a private-public key pair on your computer. When you first *receive funds* that is when it appears on the blockchain.

In other words, you don't give your address to someone by saying 'please look at transaction 7 in block 317592', you just give them your address. It is the same with your bank account, you just give them your bank account!

Answer (score 0):

First, publishing anyone's bank account number is not a good idea as that can be used for identity theft. Second, there are a lot of identity solutions like [onename](https://www.onename.com/), which may be closer to what you want to do. There's also [BIP47](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0047.mediawiki), which allow anyone to publish a single public key whose transactions are not known to anyone but the sender and receiver.